# How to retrieve everything below a given registry key?

Tags: vbscript, registry, recursive-query

I have one script retrieve all registry values in a specific key (Ex: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET`), but I need consult in making that search recursive. I need print all registry and subkeys below this key (Ex: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET`)

Example for my script:

```
For Each strSubkey In arrSubKeys
  Set objHtml=fso.Opentextfile(strComputer & ".txt",intForWriting,Createfile)

  strValue = Null

  strSubKeyPath = pathKeyReg & "\" & strSubkey
  objRegistry.EnumValues hDefKey, strSubKeyPath, arrValueNames, arrTypes

  For i = LBound(arrValueNames) To UBound(arrValueNames)
    strValueName = arrValueNames(i)
    Select Case arrTypes(i)
      Case REG_SZ          
        objRegistry.GetStringValue hDefKey, strSubKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
        objHtml.WriteLine strSubKeyPath & vbTab & strValueName & vbTab & "(REG_SZ)" & vbTab & strValue 

      ' Show a REG_EXPAND_SZ value
      Case REG_EXPAND_SZ
        objRegistry.GetExpandedStringValue hDefKey, strSubKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
        objHtml.Write strSubKeyPath & vbTab & strValueName & vbTab & "(REG_EXPAND_SZ)" & vbTab & strValue
    End Select
  Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to recurse into subkeys for that. Wrap your code in a procedure and add code that [enumerates the subkeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the current key and calls itself for each subkey.

```
Sub RecurseKey(key)
  'enumerate values (your existing code)
  objRegistry.EnumValues hDefKey, key, names, types
  If Not IsNull(names) Then
    For i = 0 To UBound(names)
      name = names(i)
      Select Case types(i)
        Case REG_SZ          
          ...
        Case REG_EXPAND_SZ
          ...
        Case ...
      End Select
    Next
  End If

  'enumerate subkeys and recurse
  objRegistry.EnumKey hDefKey, key, subKeys
  If Not IsNull(subKeys) Then
    For Each sk In subKeys
      RecurseKey key & "\" & sk  '<-- recursion happens here
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```